# Google Bookmark Export date format?

Tags: date, formatting, export, bookmarks

I been working on parsing out bookmarks from an export file generated by google bookmarks. This file contains the following date attributes:

ADD_DATE="1231721701079000"

ADD_DATE="1227217588219000"

These are not standard unix style timestamps. Can someone point me in the right direction here? I'll be parsing them using c# if you are feeling like really helping me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1231721701079000 looks suspiciously like time since Jan 1st, 1970 in microseconds.

```
perl -wle 'print scalar gmtime(1231721701079000/1_000_000)'
Mon Jan 12 00:55:01 2009
```

I'd make some bookmarks at known times and try it out to confirm.

Answer (score 21):

Chrome uses a modified form of the Windows Time format (“[Windows epoch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/06/9461176.aspx)”) for its timestamps, both in the `Bookmarks` file and the history files. The Windows Time format is the number of 100ns-es since January 1, 1601. The Chrome format is the number of microseconds since the same date, and thus 1/10 as large.

To convert a Chrome timestamp to and from the Unix epoch, you must convert to seconds and compensate for the difference between the two base date-times (11644473600).

Here’s the conversion formulas for Unix, JavaScript (Unix in milliseconds), Windows, and Chrome timestamps (you can rearrange the +/× and -/÷, but you’ll lose a little precision):

```
u :  Unix       timestamp    eg: 1378615325
j :  JavaScript timestamp    eg: 1378615325177
c :  Chrome     timestamp    eg: 13902597987770000
w :  Windows    timestamp    eg: 139025979877700000

u =  (j / 1000)
u =  (c - 116444736000000)   / 10000000
u =  (w - 1164447360000000)  / 100000000

j =  (u * 1000)
j =  (c - 116444736000000)   / 10000
j =  (w - 1164447360000000)  / 100000

c =  (u * 10000000)          + 116444736000000
c =  (j * 10000)             + 116444736000000
c =  (w / 10)

w =  (u * 100000000)         + 1164447360000000
w =  (j * 100000)            + 1164447360000000
w =  (c * 10)
```

Note that these are pretty big numbers, so you’ll need to use 64-bit numbers or else handle them as strings like with PHP’s BC-math module.

Comment: But the answer is about exported `bookmarks_mm.dd.yyyy.html` http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Chrome_bookmarks

Comment: I came here looking for chrome epoch to unix timestamp. The formula above didn't work for me. I tested with value for today (27 April 2018).

`c = 13169330714873550`. 

Formula supplied above
`u = (c - 116444736000000)   / 10000000 => 2011-05-13...`

Corrected formula
`u = (c - 11644473600000000) / 1000000 => 2018-04-27...`

Answer (score 8):

In Javascript the code will look like this

```
function chromeDtToDate(st_dt) {
   var microseconds = parseInt(st_dt, 10);
   var millis = microseconds / 1000;
   var past = new Date(1601, 0, 1).getTime();
   return new Date(past + millis);
}
```

Comment: It's the answer about `bookmarks_mm.dd.yyyy.html`, not about `Bookmarks[.json]`.

Answer (score 4):

As of the newest Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit):

- When I export bookmark, I got an html file like "bookmarks_3_22_19.html".
- And each item has an 'add_date' field which contains date string. like this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" add_date="1553220774" icon="">Stack Overflow</a>
```

- This timestamp is actually **seconds** (not microseconds) since Jan 1st, 1970. So we can parse it with Javascript like following code:

```
function ChromeTimeToDate(timestamp) {
   var seconds = parseInt(timestamp, 10);
   var dt = new Date();
   dt.setTime(seconds * 1000);
   return dt;
}
```

- For the upper example link, we can call `ChromeTimeToDate('1553220774')` to get Date.

```
ChromeTimeToDate('1553220774')
12:09:03.263 Fri Mar 22 2019 10:12:54 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 3):

Eureka!  I remembered having read the ADD_DATE’s meaning at some website, but until today, I could not find it again.

> [http://MSDN.Microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753582(v=vs.85).aspx](http://MSDN.Microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

offers this explanation as a “Note” just before the heading “Exports and Imports”:

> “Throughout this file[-]format definition, {date} is a decimal integer that represents the number of seconds elapsed since midnight January 1, 1970.”

Before that, examples of {date} were shown:

> <DT><H3 FOLDED ADD_DATE="{date}">{title}</H3>
>   …

and

> <DT><A HREF="{url}" ADD_DATE="{date}" LAST_VISIT="{date}" LAST_MODIFIED="{date}">{title}</A>
>   …

Someday, I will write a VBA macro to convert these to recognizable dates, *but not today!*

If someone else writes a conversion script first, please share it.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a macro, but it's what I just used, so here it is: double add_date = 1547960062; DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1); dt = dt.AddSeconds(add_date);

Answer (score 2):

Initially looking at it, it almost looks like if you chopped off the last 6 digits you'd get a reasonable Unix Date using the [online converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)

1231721701 = Mon, 12 Jan 2009 00:55:01 GMT

1227217588 = Thu, 20 Nov 2008 21:46:28 GMT

The extra 6 digits could be formatting related or some kind of extended attributes.

There is some sample code for the [conversion of Unix Timestamps](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/Convert-a-Unix-timestamp-to-a-.NET-DateTime.aspx) if that is in fact what it is.

Comment: Schwern was correct, but I gave you a vote for the link which is the code I was using for converting unix timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

look here for code samples: http://www.epochconverter.com/#code

```java
// my groovy (java) code finally came out as:

def convertDate(def epoch)

{

    long dv = epoch / 1000; // divide by 1,000 to avoid milliseconds

    String dt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (dv));

   // to get epoch date: 

   //long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("01/01/1970 01:00:00").getTime() * 1000;

    return dt;

} // end of def
```

So firefox bookmark date exported as json gave me:

```
json.lastModified :1366313580447014

convert from epoch date:18/Apr/2013 21:33:00
```

from :

```
println "convert from epoch date:"+convertDate(json.lastModified)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ConvertToDateTime(srcChromeBookmarkDate) {
    //Hp --> The base date which google chrome considers while adding bookmarks
    var baseDate = new Date(1601, 0, 1);

    //Hp --> Total number of seconds in a day.
    var totalSecondsPerDay = 86400;

    //Hp --> Read total number of days and seconds from source chrome bookmark date.
    var quotient = Math.floor(srcChromeBookmarkDate / 1000000);
    var totalNoOfDays = Math.floor(quotient / totalSecondsPerDay);
    var totalNoOfSeconds = quotient % totalSecondsPerDay;

    //Hp --> Add total number of days to base google chrome date.
    var targetDate =  new Date(baseDate.setDate(baseDate.getDate() + totalNoOfDays));

    //Hp --> Add total number of seconds to target date.
    return new Date(targetDate.setSeconds(targetDate.getSeconds() + totalNoOfSeconds));
}

var myDate = ConvertToDateTime(13236951113528894);
var alert(myDate);
//Thu Jun 18 2020 10:51:53 GMT+0100 (Irish Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Python program

import time

d = 1630352263   #for example put here, if (ADD_DATE="1630352263")

print(time.ctime(d))  #Mon Aug 30 22:37:43 2021 - you will see
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.